# Tool for documentation of TreeViews

Tags: documentation, treeview

I need to task someone (unexperienced) to do a documentation and include screenshots of treeviews containing icons and text, similar to a File explorer (but with different, existing icon images). I cannot take shots from real live applications yet.

Is there any tool that I can give my guys to support this without the need of coding. Best would be a tool where one would enter a small tree, select an icon to go beside the text, click [OK] and a picture appears showing the treeview representation of what has been entered.

Naive ???

Thanks for your advise

Kind regards MikeD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution myself.

I gave an XHTML template to my staff consisting of nested UL/LI elements which they can edit using Wordpad. The HTML template references a CSS I constructed, which cares for displaying the correct icon image.

I have coded a default set of icons into the CSS, and gave them the possibility to optionally choose a specific icon by using a specific "class" attribute in the LI tag.

Users themselves find the construction of nested UL/LI rather straightforward and can immediately see the result in a browser. When they are happy with the tree they print out the page as a PDF which is then embedded into the documentation.

Thanks & good luck
MikeD